# how to call another apllication(for which i dont have source code) from my android application

Tags: android

I want to call another application like another game app from my application by pressing a button in my application. Im new to android and im not getting anything. someone please help me in this

Comment: Read this http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this by using of bellow code,

just you have to know that which application you want to open and the package name of this application.

```
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

You can check it by using this code,

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
    if (i == null)
        throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
    else
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.name");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

}
```